# Unable to log in to facebook using Python & Selenium. send_keys() not doing anything

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a script to login to facebook. Based on some tutorials, I have written this so far.

When the following is executed, it just launches Firefox, goes to facebook.com and waits there and just fails. The username and password dont get entered and the login button doesnt get clicked.

What could I be doing wrong? I think my XPath Ids are correct, checked with Firepath. Any hint is appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    import unittest

    class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

        def setUp(self):
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
            self.driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")

        def test_Login(self):
            driver = self.driver
            fbUsername = "myemail@gmail.com"
            fbPassword = "mypassword"
            emailFieldID = ".//*[@id='email']"
            passFieldID = ".//*[@id='pass']"
            loginButtonXPath = ".//input[@value='Log In']"
            flLogoXpath = "(//a[contains(@href, 'logo')])[1]"


            emailFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(emailFieldID))
            passFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(passFieldID))
            loginButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(loginButtonXPath))

            emailFieldElement.click()
            emailFieldElement.clear()
            emailFieldElement.send_keys(fbUsername)

            passFieldElement.click()
            passFieldElement.clear()
            passFieldElement.send_keys(fbPassword)
            loginButtonElement.click()
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(flLogoXpath))


        def tearDown(self):
            self.driver.quit()



    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://facebook.com")

email = "email"
password = "pass"
login="loginbutton"
emailelement = driver.find_element_by_name(email)
passwordelement = driver.find_element_by_name(password)
emailelement.send_keys("USERNAME")
passwordelement.send_keys("PASSWORD")
loginelement = driver.find_element_by_id(login)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have done wrong here is, you have declared the selectors as `xpath` and you are using the method to search for the `WebElement` using id.

Change the `find_element_by_id` to `find_element_by_xpath` and your problem would be solved.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import unittest

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")

    def test_Login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        fbUsername = "myemail@gmail.com"
        fbPassword = "mypassword"
        emailFieldID = ".//*[@id='email']"
        passFieldID = ".//*[@id='pass']"
        loginButtonXPath = ".//input[@value='Log In']"
        flLogoXpath = "(//a[contains(@href, 'logo')])[1]"

        emailFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(emailFieldID))
        passFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(passFieldID))
        loginButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(loginButtonXPath))

        emailFieldElement.click()
        emailFieldElement.clear()
        emailFieldElement.send_keys(fbUsername)

        passFieldElement.click()
        passFieldElement.clear()
        passFieldElement.send_keys(fbPassword)
        loginButtonElement.click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(flLogoXpath))


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: If you want to continue using `find_element_by_id`, pass only the id as the selector. For example, for email field, it should be, `driver.find_element_by_id("email")` and likewise for others.

Answer (score 1):

I have done the same test using java. You might want to take a look to find your error.

```
// Creates a driver object for firefox
    WebDriver driver_xpath = new FirefoxDriver();

    // Goto page
    driver_xpath.get(Address);
    // email box-->email address-->click
    driver_xpath.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys(UserID);
    // password box-->password-->click
    driver_xpath.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pass']")).sendKeys(Password);
    // login button-->click
    driver_xpath.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='loginbutton']")).click();
    // Navigation drop button-->click
    driver_xpath.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='userNavigationLabel']")).click();
    //Waits for the drop down menu to show
    driver_xpath.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    // logout button-->click
    driver_xpath.findElement(By.xpath("//li[12]/a/span/span")).click();
    //Close
    driver_xpath.close();
```